# Laravel Horizon installed within one module to monitor queues in another module, both of which are using the same Redis?

Tags: php, laravel, redis, queue, horizon

New to Redis and Horizon!

Having wo laravel projects hosted in same server,using same database and common redis service.

Let's say the projects are `X` and `Y`.

I have configured Laravel Horizon in X and its running fine. I'm able to monitor all the queues running inside this. running the worker inside in `X`

`php artisan queue:work --queue=Xqueue,Yqueue`

The same way there are some queues inside `Y`. So i want to know that is it possible to monitor the queues in `Y` using the horizon that is configured in `X`

NOTE: using same redis link and configuration in both

When i run the command `php artisan queue:work --queue=Xqueue,Yqueue` in `X`. and dispatch a job in `Y` by running dispatch(new TestJob())->onQueue('Yqueue'); .

The job was failing all the time.
I am not sure if it possible, or this is the correct way.

So what i want know is is it possible queues in `X` and `Y` should be monitored by the horizon configured in `X`. or what I have to do ?

Comment: try to put the name of queue in project Y on the `horizon.php` of project X. to do this, add like:
`'supervisor-1' => [
            'queue' => ['Xqueue', 'Yqueue'],
        ],` 
I don't know if that works, but you monitor those queues by the name

Comment: Tried that, the job was taken by the worker but was failing.